# Python (Django) or PHP?

Tags: php, python, web-deployment

I'm trying to decide whether or not I should continue on with learning Django for web development or to switch to PHP, since the latter seems to be more in-demand on the job market. I enjoy Python and think it's terrific but this is a matter of practicality. Any thoughts?

Comment: Work on work you love. :)

Answer (score 0):

This thread is probably going to be flagged as off topic but my personal opinion would be that if you already know Python you can probably pickup Django much faster than a php framework esp if you have to learn php from scratch.